# Solidity - Invalid character in string

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I'm working on a Solidity ERC20 Smart Contract that needs verbiage from latin based countries.
I'm using Remix ETH online IDE

How Can I add special characters without the compiler yelling at me?

currently:

`string public responsavel = "Estado de SÃO PAULO Coçar";`

this errors as: ParserError: `Invalid character in string.`

Essentially it doesn't like `ç` and `Ã`, but I need those as well as future `é`, `ô` characters and such.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the UTF-8 sequence

```
string public responsavel = "Estado de S\xC3\x83O PAULO Co\xC3\xA7ar";
```

Comment: thank you - could you point me to an online source where I can find more UTF-8 sequences for my other uses cases? Also would this compile on a human readable manner afterwards once I throw this contract for verification on BSCScan or EtherScan?

Comment: This is the first convertor that I found on Google - https://mothereff.in/utf-8 ... Since BSCScan and EtherScan encode the rest of the page in UTF-8, it's going to display correctly. But other resources that don't use UTF-8 are going to display it unexpectedly (depending on what encoding they use).

Comment: thank you so much - sorry for such a newbie question - but what's the equivalent to `console.log()` in Solidity? I'm trying to log values on the Remix IDE.

Comment: Solidity contracts don't have any UI (not even) console on their own, so there is no `print()` or `console.log()` by design. However, you can use event logs for example - https://imgur.com/a/AwFvgby

Comment: Got it. so in the case on Remix even by writing that helper method you've showed I'd still wouldn't be able to see anything printed with those values?

Comment: You can see the event log in my example - https://imgur.com/a/JRiHUfe ... It just acts differently from the JS `console.log()`, that's why I highlighted the difference.